# Heroku python edit html and update

Tags: python, heroku

I am working on creating a project website using heroku with python. Following the tutorial at heroku.com, I have clone the "python-getting-started" and it created the website as the image below. Now I want to edit this webpage as I need, like title and the content and coloring. But when I edit the index.html file in python-getting-started/hello/ folder, and save it and go to the webpage. It didnt get updated as I editted. I don't know how should I edit the webpage as I need. Can you please teach me how?

I cannot upload the image, but it is the sample webpage that heroku's "python-getting-started".

Comment: Did you committed and pushed the updated changes.

Comment: got it work. Thanks for the hint.